# How to use action attribute in HTML properly?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a form in HTMl. However, I don't know how to make the action attribute work. Below I have attached my code. The form appears, but when I enter the information, it isn't added to the PHP file.

```
<form action="info.php">
    <p>Username: 
        <input type="text" name="username" size="15" maxlegnth="30" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Another question. When I'm linking things (images, videos, etc.) to my website, do I need to attach the whole link (file:///C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Web%20Developement%20Code/notes.php) or is notes.php enough?
Thank you!

Comment: "when I enter the information, it isn't added to the PHP file" — what do you mean? Your form doesn’t have a submit button and if it did, do you have code in place to do something with the submitted value?

Comment: Instead of a submit button, I just click enter. It takes me to a blank page. When I check the PHP file, nothing new has been added to it.

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set method="post" to form, and add submit button, then you will be able to get your information.

```
<form method="post" action="info.php">
  <p>Username: 
    <input type="text" name="username" size="15" maxlegnth="30" />
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Then in info.php:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo($username) //or any other actions with this variable
```

In response to your second question, you don't need to provide the full path. It is enough to specify the path from the root folder of your project.

> Another question. When I'm linking things (images, videos, etc.) to my website, do I need to attach the whole link (file:///C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Web%20Developement%20Code/notes.php) or is notes.php enough?

Comment: What do you mean by in info.php? Also thank you very much.

Comment: I wrote the code for the example, which must be in the file "info.php" to get the variable that you pass from the form. The link to the file "info.php" was written in your example in the action parameter. If this file doesn't exist, create it and copy my code there.

Comment: I added everything you told me to add, but it still doesn't work. It takes me to info.php (with the <?php code in it) and the username isn't saved.What should I do now?

Comment: you just need to setup a local web server with PHP. Check out XAMPP: [http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). If you have macOS, try MAMP [https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/mac/](https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/mac/)

Comment: I did this, but the same thing happens. What now?

Comment: [https://youtu.be/K-qXW9ymeYQ](https://youtu.be/K-qXW9ymeYQ) there is a guide how to install and run xampp